# How to save/open custom program with a custom extension in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I am writing a small program using Windows Form Application in C#, .Net platform. Let's say I have made a paint app and want to save the picture I have done. How can I save the changes I made and open it up again so that I can change some of the parts using my program? Like the default Paint program in windows I want to save it and open it back again. It does not have to be a paint program or txt file, generally how can I save the work I have made in a custom program and save it with the extension of my program (let's say .paint).

Comment: Did you do any research or try something yourself?

Comment: This question is not specific. For saving a file and open it in .NET should be very easy. There is the System.IO namespace, however what you want to write into the file that is the real question. You can serialize object as (binary, XML, JSON) or create CSV files, .xlsx, .docx, pdf, etc... you can invent your own file structure. If you want to save images use System.Drawing namespace Image object it has Save() method.
So I suggest you to decide what do you want to save, and ask the question again. Because there is no good answer to this question now.

Comment: Assume Autocad. When you do your work and save it, it is saving it as .cad and the Logo of the software company is seen on the file. When you click the file to open, it is associated with Autocad software. I did do research but couldn't find anything on the internet. If you can, please share it with me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Write an installer which can associate your file extension with your program.
2. On your program start up check Windows registry if your file extension is associated with your program or not, if not then associate yourself so next time user simply click the file and your program automatically opens

Sample code:

```
public static void SetAssociation(string Extension, string KeyName, string OpenWith, string FileDescription)
{
    CurrentUser = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\FileExts\\" + Extension, true);
    CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey("UserChoice", false);
    CurrentUser.Close();

    // Tell explorer the file association has been changed
    SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void SHChangeNotify(uint wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);
```

You need admin privileges to run this program.